# Why isn't my extension of the HTMLCalendar class working the way I want it to?

Tags: python, html

Here's my code.

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar


class MyCalendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def formatday(self, day, weekday, *data):
        """
        Return a day as a table cell.
        """
        if day == 0:
            # day outside month
            return '<td class="%s">&nbsp;</td>' % self.cssclass_noday
        elif day in data: # check to see if the current day is in data
            return '<td class="%s"><a href="/events/%d">%d</a></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, day)
        else:
            return '<td class="%s">%d</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)

    def formatweek(self, theweek, *data):
        """
        Return a complete week as a table row.
        """
        if len(data) == 0:
            s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd) for (d, wd) in theweek)
        else:
            s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd, data) for (d, wd) in theweek)
        return '<tr>%s</tr>' % s

    def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, withyear=True, *data):
        """
        Return a formatted month as a table.
        """
        v = []
        a = v.append
        a('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="%s">' % (
            self.cssclass_month))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, withyear=withyear))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatweekheader())
        a('\n')
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth):
            a(self.formatweek(week, data))
            a('\n')
        a('</table>')
        a('\n')
        return ''.join(v)


data = [3, 4]

print(MyCalendar(6).formatmonth(2023, 2, 3))
print(MyCalendar(6).formatmonth(2023, 2, data))
```

I want the class to take some data as input, and then for each day that is part of data, make it a hyperlink. I can't figure out what I'm missing. I found a previous thread where they only modified the formatday and formatweek methods, but that didn't work so I tried also changing formatmonth but so far nothing has worked as intended. Any input would be appreciated!

Edit:
**Expected outcome:** method loops as normal, checking each 'day' for its presence in 'data', and if found, printing a link instead of just a plain text date. (Added comment in code to reflect this)

**Actual outcome:** whether I pass data as a single int value, or a list, I receive the same unmodified calendar output.

**Notes:** There are no errors output; the program is operating as originally designed - the modification seems to have no effect.
I hope this is an acceptable explanation.

Expected Output:

```
<table>...<td class="fri"><a href="/events/3">3</a></td>...</table>
```

Actual Output:

```
<table>...<td class="fri">3</td>...</table>
```

Edit 2:
I tried moving the '*data' parameter before the 'withyear' parameter as follows:

```
def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, withyear=True, *data):
```

but the output hasn't changed.

Edit 3:
Okay, so I figured out some portion of my problem but I don't fully understand it but I think '*data' is unpacking my list and passing it individually to this line:

```
s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd, data) for (d, wd) in theweek)
```

so I changed the '*data' parameter to 'data' and passing one integer as 'data' works and I get the intended output; however when I try to pass more than one in a list I get this error:

```
elif day in data:
^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

so I think it's still separating my list at that line.

Is there some way to pass a list as a parameter and specify that it not be unpacked?

Comment: What exactly happens, what should happen? If there are error messages show them completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I don't know if it automatically notifies you that I edited my post, but I added some clarification on the problem I am having! :)

Comment: There is no automatic notification of an edit. In the last line the call to "formatmonth" assigns the "data" argument in the call to the "withyear" parameter of the method "formatmonth".

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried executing the last line including the 'withyear=True' parameter and received this error: `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` so then I edited the program to take the '*data' parameter before the 'withyear' parameter. The output remained the same, however.

Comment: I added some more information to the post because I was able to get it to work properly with a single value passed, but passing the list doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out! My solution was passing the values for data as a tuple.

I'll add the corrected code below.

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar

class MyCalendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def formatday(self, day, weekday, data):
        """
        Return a day as a table cell.
        """
        if day == 0:
            # day outside month
            return '<td class="%s">&nbsp;</td>' % self.cssclass_noday
        elif day in data:
            return '<td class="%s"><a href="/events/%d">%d</a></td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day, day)
        else:
            return '<td class="%s">%d</td>' % (self.cssclasses[weekday], day)

    def formatweek(self, theweek, data):
        """
        Return a complete week as a table row.
        """
        if data is None:
            s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd) for (d, wd) in theweek)
        else:
            s = ''.join(self.formatday(d, wd, data) for (d, wd) in theweek)
        return '<tr>%s</tr>' % s

    def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, data, withyear=True):
        """
        Return a formatted month as a table.
        """
        v = []
        a = v.append
        a('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="%s">' % (
            self.cssclass_month))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, withyear=withyear))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatweekheader())
        a('\n')
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth):
            a(self.formatweek(week, data))
            a('\n')
        a('</table>')
        a('\n')
        return ''.join(v)


data = (3, 4)

print(MyCalendar(6).formatmonth(2023, 2, (3,)))
print(MyCalendar(6).formatmonth(2023, 2, data))
```

Comment: The important part is that you removed the asterisks. I recommend that you should read the docs and play around a bit with asterisks in front of function parameters in function definitions and other uses (in function calls, on the left side of an assignment).

Comment: @MichaelButscher It definitely was important that I removed the asterisks, but also switching from data in a list to data in a tuple made a difference too, and I'm going to try to figure out exactly why that is, but I'm not certain as of now.